# Overloading the > operator with an array of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to compare two different objects inside an array of the object, if I don't use an array it works fine. Putting the objects in an array results in the overloading function not even being called ("yes" does not get printed). I'm not sure if I'm just using the wrong parameters inside my overloading function or what.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
public:
    myClass(int num) 
    { 
        value = num;
    }

    friend bool operator>(myClass& a, myClass& b) 
    { 
        cout << "yes" << endl; 
        return a.value > b.value; 
    }

private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    myClass *list[5];

    list[0] = new myClass(15);
    list[1] = new myClass(4);


    if (list[0] > list[1])
        cout << "yes";
    else
        cout << "no";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's an array of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list[0] > list[1]` is comparing two pointers, which does not use your overloaded operator.  To call the overloaded operator, you would need `*list[0] > *list[1]`.

By the way, the signature of `operator>` should be `bool operator>(const myClass& a, const myClass& b)`.